# Any opensource widget system for CMS

Tags: php, jquery, content-management-system, widget

I'm looking for something like Yootheme Widgetkit to implement in my CMS.

My goal is to put inside the content some marker (for example [gallery=1] ) and when the page is rendered the system place my gallery in the same position.

Yootheme widgetkit has about 60 jquery widget, accordion, gallery, menu etc...

Do you know if there is something similar to implment in a custom CMS?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try jQuery UI? http://jqueryui.com/home But unfortunatelly it doesn't have gallery support.

The jQuery UI library is currently available for use in all personal or commercial projects under both MIT and GPL licenses.